# Create or replace table DB2?

Tags: db2

As part of a python script i am running the 3 following SQL statements in order to create a backup copy before the rest of the code updates the main table:

```
DROP TABLE TABLEAU.TESTTABLEJBCOPY;
CREATE TABLE TABLEAU.TESTTABLEJBCOPY LIKE TABLEAU.TESTTABLEJB;
INSERT INTO TABLEAU.TESTTABLEJBCOPY (SELECT * FROM TABLEAU.TESTTABLEJB);
```

This works fine except in the instances where the table `TABLEAU.TESTTABLEJBCOPY` dosen't exist.

I have tried using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TABLEAU.TESTTABLEJBCOPY LIKE TABLEAU.TESTTABLEJB;
INSERT INTO TABLEAU.TESTTABLEJBCOPY (SELECT * FROM TABLEAU.TESTTABLEJB);
```

however it keeps pulling up the error

> Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "TABLE" was found following "CREATE OR REPLACE ".  Expected tokens may include:  "TYPE".  SQLSTATE=42601
>    SQLCODE=-104

Which i am not sure how to handle.

Alternatively would there be a better way to make it check to see if the table doesn't exist before trying to drop the table.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you simply delete all the rows?

Comment: @ Dan Bracuk The script won't always be run necessarily using these tables and so the copy table won't always exist to delete rows from. Hence why i need a create or replace style function.

Comment: @Josh - what Dan was getting at is "just create the table during database creation, then (if you use it), just clear the table first".

Comment: Although I have problems with your process as I currently understand it; you can only run one update process at a time, or get bizarre results.  I'd look into doing something like saving the snapshot into a temp/random table, or doing work on the snapshot table, or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Db2-Linux/Unix/Windows up to version 11.1, there is no such syntax as "create or replace table" . Other Db2 platforms may vary (because syntax varies accross z/OS, i-series, and Linux/Unix/Windows).

From Db2 for Linux/Unix/Windows at v11.5, IBM added new syntax `create table ... if not exists`  and  `drop table ... if exists`.

For versions older than V11.5, you can drop the table first (and ignore the warning if it does not exist), and then create the table.
You can script to ignore the SQLSTATE corresponding to the failure of drop table if the table does not exist.

You can also you compound SQL to query if the table exists before dropping it. This is frequently asked. The mechanism can vary with you Db2 server operating-system platform also.

For the purpose of creating a backup-copy of a table, you can also consider adding a timestamp to the tablename (as suffix or prefix) before using CREATE TABLE LIKE. Then you are less likely to need to drop the table (except for manually later on when you know you no longer need the backup copy).

Comment: `There is no such syntax...` Well, I just used that syntax on our iSeries. See: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/sqlp/rbafyreplacetable.htm. Unless it's only available on IBM i?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see the table exists before deletion.

Think of atomic as automatic in line.

```
BEGIN ATOMIC                 
IF( EXISTS(                  
SELECT 1 FROM tables          
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mylib'  
AND TABLE_NAME = 'mytable'
)) THEN                      
DROP table  mylib.mytable;  
END IF;                      
END;
```